# How to add and play extracted youtube files on rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, music, youtube

When I used to have Windows, I used to be able to save the file I was downloading to a custom folder and then drag that file to Windows Media Player. Is there any way to do the same on Rhythmbox? When I downloaded a youtube file today, I saved it to a custom folder in the music folder, thinking I could import it to Rhythmbox like I do any other extracted music. But when I click "Import," there are no files that can be imported from the music folder and even with the right plugins that I installed, the box shows "Not Playing"

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is because Rhythmbox is music player. Try to open video files in "Video" application or install other videoplayers in Software Manager

For example, to install VLC player, execute next coomand in terminal:

```
sudo aptitude install vlc
```

Comment: You could also install banshee which does video and audio quite well.